# Vowpal Wabbit Online Normalization -- Possible to parallelize?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, mini-batch-gradient-descent

Vowpal Wabbit (VW) uses online normalization as explained here [1].

When running VW with multiple workers, workers synchronize their models with an AllReduce at the end of each epoch.

Is it possible or is there any code/paper that explores the idea of **doing online learning with multiple workers in a parameter server setting**?

[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.6646